# toilet doesn't flush even after 2 plumber visits, to snake the sewer and also use a toilet auger

Tags: toilet

plumber said that stuff builds up in the actual toilet that blocks it. He used the auger and it flushed. Two uses later, it did the same thing- fill up and very very slowly drain, rather than the usual flush. He said we need a new toilet, but I am not seeing that kind of comment anywhere.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info to help you, such as the make of the toilet, and perhaps a picture of it and/or the plumbing beneath.

Comment: do you have any small children?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple test:
Fill the bowl slowly until the water level reaches its maximum.
Once there take a small bucket, about the size of a ice cream pail, and quickly pour it into the bowl. This should start the siphonic action and make the toilet "flush".
If this works then the main jet is plugged and can sometimes be temporarily cleared by putting a small screwdriver into the jet and gently clearing it of build up.
If it does flush with the test and you can't clear the jet, a new bowl is required.
Cost would say complete toilet replacement.

Additionally, check to make sure the fill valves bowl primer tube is attached to the overflow tube so that the priming water is pouring into it and not into the tank itself.
If the bowl isn't being properly primed, a large portion of the flush action is being used to fill the bowl instead of inducing the syphonic action and clearing the bowl of waste and can cause the waste to become plugged in the goose neck (s-trap) or shortly after.

Comment: What is your definition of cost?

Comment: Typically finding a bowl to match the existing tank would cost more in money and time then just replacing the pair as a match set. If the jet is plugged I would safely guess it's an older toilet. Most have the date of manufacturing stamped under the tank lid or just inside the tank.

Answer (score 0):

I had a toilet that wouldn't flush once and the problem was traced to the main sewer line exiting the house.  It has been crushed by a truck driving over it.

Comment: How old is the house? Slow flush could indicate roots in the drain line. I found out the undesirable way that my floor drains and weeper were connected to the main sewer line. Have you ran the sink for a while to see if it drains slow?